# Google's Backup and Sync using 4.5 Gb of memory?

Tags: memory, google-backup-and-sync

I just noticed that on my Macbook Pro, "Backup and Sync from Google" is using 4.5 Gb of memory (see Activity Monitor below). This seems like an abnormally large amount? How can I alleviate this?

[image]

Comment: How much is it backing up right now?